# How is a AWS ES test domain different from production?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am confused what a test domain is on AWS ES.

I created a test domain using this guide:
[Getting Started with Amazon Elasticsearch Service - Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-gsg.html)

I got around 8gb of storage, which is enough for my usecase for the time being.

There is another guide, right after the one above:
[Creating and Managing Amazon Elasticsearch Service Domains - Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-createupdatedomains.html)

This guide is for production. What does that mean?
Can I not use the test domain for my usecase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Production domains use Multi-AZ and dedicated master nodes for higher availability.
> - Development and testing domains use a single Availability Zone.
> - Custom domains let you choose from all configuration options.

So a test domain can still be pretty 'powerful' and you can still use them for your non-test needs, but the availability is not going to be as high as a production domain where the information is spread across AZ's

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-createupdatedomains.html